# Resize bitmaps vs multiple Images folders for Android resolutions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I'm developing an Android app but I'm still in experienced with some SDK stuff.
One of those things is multiple resolutions.

I know that the Android documentation talks about using multiple image folders for different screen resolutions.  But I ask myself, how can I reduce my app size? And that's where I thought about resizing images. Plus, I unpacked some apps and saw that they used just one folder, for one image.

My questions are, should I resize my images or should I use many images for multiple folders? What is the difference? What do people usually do? What are the advantages and disadvantages?

I'm really thinking about getting the Android device density and resizing my image accordingly. But I don't know if this is a best practice.

Comment: Too many questions packed into a single one.

Comment: Actually is just one.. I dont think it makes sense create one topic for one phrase that is on context of others

Comment: Actually, I see many question marks. Not just one.

Comment: Ok, maybe you can answer just one question then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does it's best to resize images when missing in the proper folder.
For quality sake you should alway scale **down**, not up.
So, it could be enough if you use the highest resolution image in its folder.

Better if you use it the proper dpi for that resolution. i.e.: **480 dpi** for a **drawable-xxhdpi** image.

---

Now here is my way to manage graphics.

I prefer using as little images as possible, ad put them in each folder (each at proper dpi, since I really dislike 72 dpi images).

For instance, to fill a background, I use tiled bitmaps instead of full size ones, which saves me a lot of bytes.

I also take advantage of gradients and layer-lists, to combine a tiled image and a gradient, so to say.

I also use **drawables** (which are scalable, since they are drawn at runtime) and **9 patches** (these ones are selectively stretchable).

And I also take advantage of **Unicode glyphs** (the few that Android supports): they are scalable by definition, since they are part of a **TTF** font.

Sometimes I also use **SVG graphics** (which are vectorial), through the use of an external library.
The other side of the medal is that you better keep the images simple, since they are stored in memory and you have to calculate the size in pixels when creating the bitmaps from them.
And sometimes the library isn't very fast and optimized, so it may introduce some lags.

---

I think I've been quite logorroic, but I gave you a rough idea about how to design an UI that can be nice but not necessarily heavy.